# What should I do if I feel an answer/question needs a flag, but I'm not sure which flag to use?

Tags: discussion

The answer in question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70351640/11395264).

I can't tell whether to flag this as "spam" or NAA. On one hand, this answer is very spammy ("save yourself some major headaches and start with a great theme from (long link omitted) then checkout the extensions from one of the best developers for [phpBB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpBB), sitesplat") and sounds like an ad. On the other hand, it doesn't seem to answer the question. Should I even flag it, and if I should, what should I flag it as?

Comment: Looks a bit suspect, but not quite spammy, especially given the user. Bigger issue is that it's barely more than a link-only answer. "Yes, it's possible, install this, look at this..." without any actual explanation of how it's done

Comment: @CertainPerformance So should I try and flag for NAA or should I just not flag at all?

Comment: Downvote, delete if you've got the ability, and move on.

Comment: The entire question seems to be off topic - administration and configuration of a forum software are not programming problems or similar. It might be more useful to strike for the head...

Comment: Just FYI that user has posted 12 answers, 2 in the past few months, and 5 of them are little more than links to the same paid service. They all have the same phrasing, like "I found this great theme..." so they read more like a helpful hint and less like spam

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For an old rarely visited question or answer (like the one you linked which was asked 3 months ago) if you are not sure how/if to flag doing nothing is a good option. For popular or very recent posts consider some more investigation and potentially flagging. Since flagging (except "needs moderator attention") means "please delete immediately" there is not much harm of leaving content that is not obviously bad on the site especially when no one will see it.

For the particular linked question:

- it is definitely not "NAA": one can easily understand what is written, "phpBB is high customizable" looks like an answer (granted, poorly spelled) to "can I design my own avatars fop phpBB". Recommendation to "use particular library" is perfectly fine on its own too and link is not needed to answer the question as asked.
- does not look like spam: higher reputation users are less likely to post outright spam in general. If you feel that post is spammy check if user has undisclosed affiliation or posted multiple similar/identical "answers" as well if there is some benefit one can obtain for promoting links. Note that just one of the problems does not make post "spam". In this particular case user posted link to the library twice on the same day but otherwise does not look related to it - to me it feels like author found a library and decide to post answers to mention it, it is not an only time they posted to this tag.
- post is not VLQ - same as NAA: you can read it just fine, not a link only answer.
- I don't see any other immediate problem that requires moderator intervention either.

Overall I would not flag the answer. If you feel that quality is low - downvote is always an option.

Additionally make sure to look at the question when you consider flagging an answer - answers that look link-only are frequently posted on recommendation questions - closing the question may be an additional action.